# Fatal error Unity

Tags: unity, unity2d

Importe un proyecto de Unity en el cual estaba trabajando desde mi anterior pc, y cuando lo fui a abrir me salió este error:

[image: Este es el error que me sale]

Ya Desinstale Unity y todo pero no se solucionó.

No se que hacer, ayuda.
Es urgente!
Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

El player settings se guarda en la raiz del proyecto, aveces se corrompe entre versiones y tambien da problemas cuando bajas de version por ejemplo 2022.1 -> 2019.4.

confirma que copiaste esta carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]